# How to restore SQL Server database from Azure Blob?

Tags: sql-server, azure-vm, azure-blob-storage

I created a database (IaaS) from Azure marketplace (Windows server 2012 + SQL Server Web 2014). I Selected automatic backups to blob storage. Now I'm trying to do a test restore operation.

I imported my storage account to Management Studio (on VM). By right-clicking on `bak` file in blob and than going for `Import Data-tier Application` i started a wizard:

[image]

Having followed the wizard, I chose the proper destinations for `DATA` and `LOGS` (the same directory where other databases are).

The wizard finished with an error:

[image]

Error said:

> The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource. (Microsoft.SqlServer.StorageClient)
>   The remote server returned an error: (416) The range specified is invalid for the current size of the resource.. (System)

I also tried a different approach:

I created an empty `test` database and tried to execute a `Resore` task on it. I chose `Device` and than `URL` for source. It allowed me to automatically connect to my Azure Storage account and select a `bak` file from blob.

As soon as I selected the `bak` file I got an error message:

[image]

Please note that **all** of the `bak` files have 0 Bytes size (first screen). This may have to do something with the failure.

All of the tasks I was performing form Management Studio installed automatically on the VM. Blob storage and SQL Server all came in a package form Azure marketplace.

I'm using SQL Server 2014 **Web** edition.

What am I doing wrong? How can I restore the database?